# How do you switch to zsh when using Nitrous.io

Tags: zsh, nitrousio

Any ideas? I've tried using :

> chsh -s /bin/zsh

But any password I've tried has failed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use zsh in the main console as you don't have root access, but you could utilize zsh with tmux (which is already installed on your Nitrous box).

You will just need to add this line into ~/.tmux.conf :

```
set-option -g default-shell /bin/zsh
```

Once this has been added, start a new tmux session by running:

```
tmux new -s session_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put `zsh` at the end of `~/.bashrc` to automatically start zsh in the main console when you log in.

Typing `exit` once will take you back to bash.